# Getting git commit id on Qt qmake project at make time

Tags: c++, windows, git, qt, qmake

On Windows 10 Qt 5.15, I'm getting git commit id on Qt qmake project at qmake time with

```
COMMIT = '\\"$$system(git rev-parse --verify master)\\"'
DEFINES += COMMIT_VERSION=\"$${COMMIT}\"
```

And on `main.cpp` I can print that with `qDebug() << COMMIT_VERSION;`

Since some commits do not require a full project rebuild I'm getting old (not the latest) commit ids.

How can I get that updated on every build?

Comment: What about "touching" the `main.cpp` before each build?

Comment: I didn't got what you mean, please could you be a bit more verbose?

Comment: You need to inform your build system that `main.cpp` (if that's where the reference to `COMMIT_VERSION` is) has changed every time the commit version has changed. Instead of providing the version via a compile-time definition flag, consider providing it via a file in the build tree, so that your compiler can see the `#include "version.h"` and see that `version.h` has changed.

Comment: Yeah that would be another way to do it. But (to my understanding) issue is still the same, how to ask qmake to do it at make time? Or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu but for doing what you want I try this:

what you do is like in cmd or terminal always type this **command** :

```
git rev-parse --verify master
```

so for doing this I use `QProcess` like this :

first of all, I create one bash file and put that command there.
I always put commands in one shell script file because it's easy and just put`.sh` file in the start process.

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/parisa/projectFolderName;git rev-parse --verify master
```

and this is code :

```
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess();

myProcess->start("/home/parisa/untitled1/test.sh");
myProcess->waitForFinished(3);

QString  str = myProcess->readAll();
qDebug() << "git id  : " << str;
delete myProcess;
```

and this is the output :

[image]

In **QTCreator** short cut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>G</kbd> will show you the git log.

[image]

Comment: But that will be executed at run time on linux. I'm looking to a way to get that information at build time on windows.

Comment: @KcFnMi , This way will work in windows too, but Qt Creator has an option to see commits log.

Comment: What if I want to embed commit id in the executable? What if not using QtCreator (building from command line)?

Comment: @KcFnMi , why do you want to see the commit id when you build your project?

Comment: Idea is to embed it in the application (at the time application is build) so in case of bugs the user will tell me which particular commit is presenting the bugs.